# How to convert row data to column data using pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a data frame which is of the following format:
[image]

I need the data frame with separate columns for 'Rank' and 'Percentage'. The final data should be of the following format:
[image]

Comment: please post data as text. no images. thanks!

Comment: Something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46375147/create-new-columns-from-unique-row-values-in-a-pandas-dataframe

Comment: Use: `df.pivot(['Name', 'ID', 'Year'], columns='Variable', values='Value')`

Comment: @MayankPorwal I tried doing this. I am getting a Keyerror '0'.

Comment: @BijayRegmi I tried both the methods mentioned in the solution given in the link you mentioned. set_index won't work in my case as there is duplicate data and the first solution involving pivot_table is throwing a KeyError '0'