# Python pandas dataframe pivot only works with pivot_table() but not with set_index() and unstack()

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table, attributeerror

I am trying to pivot following type of sample data in Pandas dataframe in Python. I came across couple of other stackoverflow answers that discussed how to do the pivot: [pivot_table No numeric types to aggregate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39229005/pivot-table-no-numeric-types-to-aggregate])

However, when I use `pivot_table()`, I am able to pivot the data. But when I use `set_index()` and `unstack()`, I get following error:

***AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'unstack'***

Sample Data:

```
id  responseTime    label   answers
ABC 2018-06-24  Category_1  [3]
ABC 2018-06-24  Category_2  [10]
ABC 2018-06-24  Category_3  [10]
DEF 2018-06-25  Category_1  [7]
DEF 2018-06-25  Category_8  [10]
GHI 2018-06-28  Category_3  [7]
```

Desired Output:

```
id  responseTime    category_1  category_2 category_3 category_8
ABC  2018-06-24           [3]     [10]         [10]       NULL
DEF  2018-06-25           [7]     NULL         NULL       [10]
GHI  2018-06-28           NULL    NULL         [7]        NULL
```

This works:

```
 df=pdDF.pivot_table(index=['items_id','responseTime'], columns='label', values='answers', aggfunc='first')
```

This doesn't work:

```
pdDF.set_index(['items_id','responseTime','label'], append=True, inplace=True).unstack('label')
```

I also used `pdDF[pdDF.isnull().any(axis=1)]` to make sure I don't have any NULL data in answers column. I also used `append=False` but same error happened.

From other threads, it seems `set_index()` and `unstack()` are more efficient than `pivot_table()`. I also don't want to use `pivot_table()` because it requires aggregation function and my answers column doesn't contain numeric data. I didn't want to use default (`mean()`) so I ended up using `first()`. 
Any insights on why one method works and another doesn't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'unstack'

When you use `inplace = True` in `set_index` it modified the dataframe in place. It doesn't return anything`(None)`. So you can't use `unstack` on `None` object.

> inplace : boolean, default False
>
> Modify the DataFrame in place (do not create a new object)

Use:

```
df1 = pdDF.set_index(['items_id','responseTime','label']).unstack('label')    
print(df1)

# Output:

id  responseTime    category_1  category_2 category_3 category_8
ABC  2018-06-24           [3]     [10]         [10]       NULL
DEF  2018-06-25           [7]     NULL         NULL       [10]
GHI  2018-06-28           NULL    NULL         [7]        NULL
```

Comment: Argh! Dang it, i can't believe I missed such a simple thing :) Thank you. That fixed it and I am marking your answers as Accepted.

Additionally, there was one more error in my code: `append=True` should be `append=False` because if I didn't set it to `False`, original index would be preserved along with additional columns being appended to it, and I would never go from 6 rows pivoted to 3 rows.

Comment: @rp1 Yes! That's why I didn't include `append=True` in the answer. I just forgot to mention it. Thanks:)