# python pandas set_index() and unstack results in columns with underscores in hive but pivot_table() works

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, hive, pivot-table

Related to following question I asked earlier: [Python pandas dataframe pivot only works with pivot_table() but not with set_index() and unstack()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52230219/python-pandas-dataframe-pivot-only-works-with-pivot-table-but-not-with-set-ind)

I have been able to pivot the following sample data successfully, using both `set_index()` with `unstack()` and using `pivot_table()` with `aggfunc=first` parameter.

**Sample Data**:

```
id  responseTime    label   answers
ABC 2018-06-24  Category_1  [3]
ABC 2018-06-24  Category_2  [10]
ABC 2018-06-24  Category_3  [10]
DEF 2018-06-25  Category_1  [7]
DEF 2018-06-25  Category_8  [10]
GHI 2018-06-28  Category_3  [7]
```

**Desired Output:**

```
id  responseTime    category_1  category_2 category_3 category_8
ABC  2018-06-24           [3]     [10]         [10]       NULL
DEF  2018-06-25           [7]     NULL         NULL       [10]
GHI  2018-06-28           NULL    NULL         [7]        NULL
```

**Code:**

```
#this works but having issues with reset_index so leaving it here as comment. 
#df=pdDF.pivot_table(index=['items_id','responseTime'], columns='label', values='answers', aggfunc='first')

df=pdDF.set_index(['items_id','responseTime','label']).unstack('label')

#reset the index so all columns can be preserved for table creation
df.reset_index(inplace=True)

#create pyspark dataframe from pandas dataframe after pivoting is done.
psDF=spark.createDataFrame(df)

#create hive table
psDF.write.mode('overwrite').saveAsTable('default.test_table')
```

When I use the second piece of code with `set_index()` and `unstack()`, the resulting output has additional header `answers` when printing the dataframe. This causes duplicate columns when I create a hive table out of this dataframe.

**Dataframe header before reset_index():**

```
                                   answers
id  responseTime    category_1  category_2 category_3 category_8
```

**Dataframe columns after reset_index:**

```
('items_id', '')|('responseTime', '')|('answers', u'category_1')|('answers', u'category_2')|('answers', u'cateogry_3')|('answers', u'category_8')
```

**Hive column names:**

```
_'items_id'_''_     
_'responsetime'_''_
_'answers'_u'category_1'_
_'answers'_u'category_2'_
_'answers'_u'category_3'_
_'answers'_u'category_8'_
```

I believe this is happening because `unstack()` creates hierarchical columns with multiple levels. Is there a way to make `answer` level disappear and to drop these junk underscore characters and `answer` references in the dataframe itself so I can create *normal* hive columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question here.

I can use `droplevel()` function to drop the top most level from the dataframe.

Right after `set_index()` and `unstack()`, I can add following line to drop `answer` level from the dataframe.

```
df.columns = df.columns.droplevel(0)
```

After this, `reset_index()` can be called to preserve all columns in dataframe just like the code above.

My dataframe columns and hive columns now don't contain level information with underscores.

```
|items_id|responseTime|category_1|category_2|category_3|category_8|
```

Additional reference to `droplevel()` is available on:

**Stackoverlfow Question**: [Pandas: drop a level from a multi-level column index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22233488/pandas-drop-a-level-from-a-multi-level-column-index)

**Pandas API**: 
 https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.droplevel.html#pandas.MultiIndex.droplevel