# Pivot pandas Dataframe but not able to understand the obtained output

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe that has values like this:

```
**id**   **type**    **attr**     **value**
1         type1       key1          val1
1         type1       key2          val2
2         type1       key1          val3
2         type1       key2          val4
```

And I want the output as

```
**id**   **type**    **key1**     **key2**
1          type1       val1         val2
2.         type1       val3         val4
```

I am trying to filter rows with same ids here like pick rows with same id and then create new columns as shown above.

I tried the following but getting `DataError: No numeric types to aggregate`

```
pd.pivot_table(df, values='value', index=['id', 'type'], columns='attr').reset_index()
```

UPDATE:

Solved the data error by the following modification:

```
df = pd.pivot_table(df, values='value', index=['id', 'type'], columns='attr', aggfunc='first')
```

But I am not able to understand the output that I am getting below. Why `attr`, 'key1' and `key2` columns hover above than `id` and `type`?

```
attr      key1  key2
id type
1  type1  val1  val2
2  type1  val3  val4
```

Comment: @Wen Please check my edits.

Comment: `df = pd.pivot_table(df, values='value', index=['id', 'type'], columns='attr', aggfunc='first').reset_index()`

Comment: Thanks @Wen. this worked.

Comment: The references that helped me besides @Wen's answer who told me the term as pivoting for my problem, were: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39229005/pivot-table-no-numeric-types-to-aggregate