# Pivot on non numeric types pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame.

```
date           name     start_time_bin      skill set
2019-10-25     Joe       10am- 12am          C,Python
2019-10-25     Mark      10am- 12am          Java,Python
2019-10-25     Sara      12pm- 2pm          Java,Python
2019-10-26     Jim       12pm- 2pm           C,Python, scala
2019-10-26     Bob       >=2pm < 4pm         C,SQL
```

I'm trying to convert this dataframe into something like this using pivot.

```
Audit_date    10am- 12am   12pm- 2pm      >=2pm < 4pm  
2019-10-25       Joe          Sara            Nan
2019-10-25       Mark          Nan            Nan
2019-10-26       Nan           Jim            Bob
```

I tried using the following:

`piv = new.pivot_table(index=['Audit_Date'], columns='start_time_bin', 
                      values='name')`

I'm getting error as `No numeric types to aggregate`

Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: this is to swing a frame by changing aggfunc and it is more than solved in SO

Comment: He said : No numeric types to aggregate, it is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39229005/pivot-table-no-numeric-types-to-aggregate

Comment: @ansev - It is better, closing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If never duplicates per `Audit_Date` with `start_time_bin` then is possible use aggregation by `first`:

```
piv = new.pivot_table(index='Audit_Date', 
                      columns='start_time_bin', 
                      values='name', 
                      aggfunc='first')
```

Or if possible duplicates then aggregate by `join`:

```
piv = new.pivot_table(index='Audit_Date', 
                     columns='start_time_bin', 
                     values='name', 
                     aggfunc=', '.join)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-to-pivot-a-dataframe

Comment: No numeric types to aggregate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39229005/pivot-table-no-numeric-types-to-aggregate

Comment: @ansev https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58912146/pivot-on-non-numeric-types-pandas?noredirect=1#comment104086987_58912146