# pandas.core.base.DataError: No numeric types to aggregate

Tags: python, pandas

Im new to pandas pivot table feature.
Im following this guide[1].
Im raeding an existing excel file and try to create a table output.

im trying to index the pivot table like;

```
def generate_invoice_summary_info():                                                           
    file_path = 'output.xlsx'                                                                  
    df = pd.read_excel(file_path, sheet_name='Invoice Details', usecols="E:G,I,L:N")                                                                                                          
    df["Invoice Cost Centre"] = df["Invoice Cost Centre"].astype("category")                   
    df["Invoice Cost Centre"].cat.set_categories(["RIM", "R3TM", "D3TM", "R5M"], inplace=True) 

    df['Price'] = df['Price'].astype(str)                                                      
    df['Period From'] = df['Period From'].astype(str)                                          

    pd.pivot_table(df, index=["Invoice Cost Centre", "Invoice Category"])
```

im getting following error

```
pandas.core.base.DataError: No numeric types to aggregate
```

Why do I get this error?
Im trying to summarise my table based on Invoice Cost Centre,Invoice Category columns

[1]https://pbpython.com/pandas-pivot-table-explained.html

Comment: the problem is that aggfunc by default is 'sum' and its column is numeric, you need to change `aggfunc = '' .join` or `aggfunc = 'first`

Comment: @ansev i haven't used aggfunc yet, check my above code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pivot\_table No numeric types to aggregate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39229005/pivot-table-no-numeric-types-to-aggregate)

Comment: default aggfunc is `sum`, then you have to change aggfunc as I said. aggfunc has a default value that produces the error if you do not change it when using the method

Comment: try: `pd.pivot_table(df, index=["Invoice Cost Centre", "Invoice Category"],aggfunc=''.join)`