# Changing the structure of dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

```
id|sem|stu
1|sem2|A
1|sem1|B
1|sem1|C
2|sem1|A
2|sem3|A
```

I want this to be re-modeled like this:

```
   sem1|sem2|sem3|sem4
1  B|A|NaN|NaN
1  C|A|NaN|NaN
2  A|NaN|A|NaN
```

I have tried the following code:

```
df.pivot(index='stu',columns='id',values='sub')
```

The Output is not what I expected.Could someone give their ideas?

Comment: `df.pivot_table(index = 'id',columns = 'sem',values = 'stu').rename_axis(columns = None,index = None)`

Comment: @ansev Throws an exception DataError: No numeric types to aggregate

Comment: Ups, sorry, use: `df.pivot_table(index = 'id',columns = 'sem',values = 'stu',aggfunc = ''.join).rename_axis(columns = None,index = None)`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39229005/pivot-table-no-numeric-types-to-aggregate

Comment: @SriTest Can you update the dataframe in the question to show why the suggested answers didnot work(This will be beneficial to future readers as well) , thanks

Comment: @ansev It worked.but when I have more values for 'sem' column,as it is aggregate,it joins them as a single one.Is it possible to display as separate rows.For example,for sem1 if id=1 have A and B too,is it possible to display both of them as separate values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html#pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table) witg aggfunc = `''.join` or 
another that is valid for `str` type.

```
new_df = (df.pivot_table(index = 'id',columns = 'sem',
                         values = 'stu',aggfunc = ''.join)
            .rename_axis(columns = None,index = None))
print(new_df)
  sem1 sem2 sem3
1    B    A  NaN
2    A  NaN    A
```

You could use another function to treat the values ​​deduplicated for the same ID and sem, for example `first`, although the way to not lose information here is `''.join`

---

**UPDATE**

```
print(df)
   id   sem stu
0   1  sem2   A
1   1  sem1   B
2   1  sem1   A
3   2  sem1   A
4   2  sem3   A
```

---

```
new_df=( df.assign(count=df.groupby(['id','sem']).cumcount())
           .pivot_table(index = 'id',columns = ['sem','count'],
                        values = 'stu',aggfunc = ''.join)
           .rename_axis(columns = [None,None],index = None) )
print(new_df)
  sem1      sem2 sem3
     0    1    0    0
1    B    A    A  NaN
2    A  NaN  NaN    A
```

---

```
new_df=( df.assign(count=df.groupby(['id','sem']).cumcount())
           .pivot_table(index = ['id','count'],columns = 'sem',
                        values = 'stu',aggfunc = ''.join)
           .rename_axis(columns = None,index = [None,None]) )
print(new_df)
    sem1 sem2 sem3
1 0    B    A  NaN
  1    A  NaN  NaN
2 0    A  NaN    A
```

---

**Solution without MultIndex**:

```
new_df=( df.assign(count=df.groupby(['id','sem']).cumcount())
           .pivot_table(index = 'id',columns = ['sem','count'],
                        values = 'stu',aggfunc = ''.join)
           .rename_axis(columns = [None,None],index = None) )

#Solution with duplicates names of columns
#new_df.columns = new_df.columns.droplevel(1)
#  sem1 sem1 sem2 sem3
#1    B    C    A  NaN
#2    A  NaN  NaN    A

new_df.columns = [f'{x}_{y}' for x,y in new_df.columns]
print(new_df)
  sem1_0 sem1_1 sem2_0 sem3_0
1      B      C      A    NaN
2      A    NaN    NaN      A
```

Comment: join might create problems if all dtypes are not `str` :) ?

Comment: true, really the function to apply depends on how his data is

Comment: It worked.but when I have more values for 'sem' column,as it is aggregate,it joins them as a single one.Is it possible to display as separate rows.For example,for sem1 if id=1 have A and B too,is it possible to display both of them as separate values.

Comment: Check update section:) 
In that case I am forced to duplicate the names of the columns (I do not recommend it) or use MultiIndex

Comment: @ansev MultiIndex is not ideal for me in this scenario. Is there any other workaround?

Comment: check solution without MultiIndex, another option is `new_df.columns = new_df.columns.droplevel(1)`, but it gets a duplicates columns

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you got wrong the arguments for `pivot`:

```
df.pivot('id', 'sem', 'stu')

sem sem1 sem2 sem3
id                
1      B    A  NaN
2      A  NaN    A
```

Comment: shows an exception as my id contains duplicate entries

Comment: Should't be a problem for pivot. If anything, its for these cases that it most useful @sri

Comment: i agree this is not a dupe since the OP already knew about pivot. However implementing , hence not a dupe +1

Comment: Thanks @anky sure I do agree with helping out, perhaps it is fine to close as dupe once the issue is solved thoug :)

Comment: @anky_91 ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape. This is the error I got

Comment: @yatu may be groupby +cumcount with pivot ,else pivot table. but unclear with existing example :)

Answer (score 0):

It was simply an error in your parameter args, you 'values' param is incorrect, it should be 'stu', not 'sub'.

You're trying to go from long to wide format, where you're indexing by index, setting your columns with columns, and filling indices with the values parameter.

Docs Link: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html

```
id = [1,1,2,2]
sem = ['sem2','sem1','sem1','sem3']
stu = ['A','B','A','A']
data = {'id':id, 'sem':sem, 'stu':stu}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df.pivot(index='id', columns='sem', values='stu')

sem sem1 sem2 sem3
id                
1      B    A  NaN
2      A  NaN    A
```